# How do I get the compose window in Google Inbox to go full-screen/pop out?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

How do I get the compose window in Google Inbox to go full-screen/pop out?

Previously, in Gmail, you had to [(shift) click the full-screen expand icon in the upper right corner of the compose window](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3231471?hl=en).

[image: Gmail compose window]

However, I don't see that icon anymore in the new Inbox interface.

[image: Inbox compose window]

Holding **Shift** when clicking the red plus or the keyboard shortcut **Shift + c** doesn't work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was shut down in April, 2019, and is no longer available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 4 March 2016, [it is now possible to expand the compose window to fullscreen](https://9to5google.com/2016/03/04/inbox-fullscreen-compose/).

> [image: animation of full screen feature]
>
> Just like in Gmail, you can now expand the compose window in
>   Inbox. Perfect for planning an elaborate surprise
>
> —
>   [Inbox by Gmail (@inboxbygmail) March 4, 2016](https://twitter.com/inboxbygmail/status/705800960635858944)

Answer (score 6):

They haven't built in support for pop-out / full screen yet:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/3YZPHua-IDg

Comment: I'm afraid that while this used to be true, they've remedied this lack. See [BioGeek's answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/98277/354).

Comment: @ale Almost, the editor is enlarged, but not full screen. How can it be full-screen or pop-out of the editor.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to have been implemented yet (opening the compose window "fullscreen" AKA in its own window), and as it seems it'll never be implemented (it's a trivial thing to implement, yet this has been requested 2 years ago / since 2014)!

What others that have responded here call "full screen", is just making a "virtual frame" within the same window bigger, that's all, which creates / doesn't solve issues associated with doing that (mainly when text-inverting), but also that you can't switch back-forward - or have on another screen in a multi-screen setup).

The best solution I've found is, to have Google Drive / Docs open in another window, then composing there in a Google Docs and then copy-pasting that into the Google Inbox reply / new mail window. Of course you can use any other text editing program or web app, but, like Inbox and Gmail, with Google Docs / Drive, changes are saved automatically to your Gmail account, which IMO is safer than using a stand-alone app.