# Is there a link to compose a new message in the Inbox by Gmail interface?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

The link to compose a new message in Gmail is as follows:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&tf=1&to={to}&cc={cc}&bcc={bcc}&su={subject}&body={body}`

Does the *Inbox by Gmail* interface provide a similar compose link?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Inbox by Gmail was retired in April, 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/75131) still holds true for now.

However, you could always bookmark [this link](https://mail.google.com/mail/?ibxr=0) to get back to Gmail as needed.